# Version not displayed in readthedocs

Tags: read-the-docs

Readthedocs does not display the version of my github package.
It states *latest*, while I specified the version to be `0.1.1` in my `conf.py` file:

```
version = "0.1.1"

release = version
```

The thing is that when I compile locally through `make html`, I see the version properly displayed. When I push to remote, it does not display the version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the readthedocs webhook added to your GitHub repository and set to active. You can also check it on readthedocs website in your project dashboard under Admin>Integrations.

That way whenever you make a change to your repository, readthedocs webhook would trigger a new build for your documentation and keep it up to date.